# How to change background graphic/theme in splitview on ipad?

Tags: ipad, graphic

I would to get help on changing template/graphic of my ipad app to something similar like this one below. Please give me advices how to get this done. Thank you very much.[image]

And this is what I have right now. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the more graphic view looks like a SplitView I think it actually is a master view with graphic and two sub views, one containing a toolbar. Both have headers with a graphic background.

Comment: Did you mean there is a big masterView that holds background and then 2 smaller subview which is indicated for "masterview" on left and "detailView" on the right?